# Mongodb collection as dynamic

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an application that has two similar but different objects and I want to store those objects in the same collection. What is the best way to do this? And how can I query this collection?

Today my collections is represented by:

```
public IMongoCollection<Post> Posts
{
    get
    {
        return _database.GetCollection<Post>("posts");
    }
}
```

And I have this class:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class NewTypePost
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

So, today I just can save and query using Post class. Now I want to store and retrive the both classes, Post and NewTypePost.

I tried to change the class type from Post to dynamic. But when I did this, I could not query the collections.

Comment: What's the problem with having two collections? You can always get the collection as `_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("posts")`

Comment: Both classes are too similar and used for the same porpouse. If I use two collections I wiil need two query on two places to find what I want. Mongo can store different objects. I do this on node.js, I don't know how to do the same on C# driver.

Comment: What's the way you want to perform your query? At the end you are going to have to ask for `Image` or `Message` right?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB .NET driver offers few possibilites in such cases:

#### Polymorphism

You can build a hierarchy of classes and MongoDB driver will be able to determine a type of an object it gets retrieved from the database:

```
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Post), typeof(NewTypePost))]
public abstract class PostBase
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}


public class Post: PostBase
{        
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class NewTypePost: PostBase
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

MongoDB driver will create additional field `_t` in every document which will represent corresponding class.

#### Single Class

You can still have `Post` class and use `BsonIgnoreIfNull` attribute to avoid serialization exception. MongoDB .NET driver will set those properties to `null` if they don't exist in your database.

```
public class Post
{   
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]     
    public string Message { get; set; } 
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

#### BsonDocument

You can also drop strongly-typed approach and use `BsonDocument` class which is dynamic dictionary-like structure that represents your Mongo documents

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("posts");
```

More details [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/bson_document/)

#### dynamic

Specifying `dynamic` as generic parameter of `ICollection` you should get a list of [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) that will hold all the values you have in your database.

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<dynamic>("posts");
var data = collection.Find(Builders<dynamic>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
var firstMessage = data[0].Message; // dynamically typed code
```

Comment: I'm looking for something like Polymorphism method. But how can I query on this way? Today I have something like this: dbContext.Posts.ReplaceOneAsync(o => o.Id == posts.Id, postToInsert);

Comment: Your ICollection can be still be of type `PostBase` if you query on shared fields like `Id`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have the next conn to a test database:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientSettings
{
    Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost"),
});
var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("TestDb");
```

Then I can do something like:

```
var col = database.GetCollection<Post>("posts");
var col2 = database.GetCollection<NewTypePost>("posts");
```

To get two different instances of `IMongoCollection` but pointing to the same collection in the database. Further I am able to save to each collection in the usual way:

```
col.InsertOne(new Post { Message = "m1" });
col2.InsertOne(new NewTypePost { Image = "im1" });
```

Then, I'm also able to query from those collection base on the specific fields:

```
var p1= col.Find(Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.Message, "m1")).FirstOrDefault();
var p2 =col2.Find(Builders<NewTypePost>.Filter.Eq(x=>x.Image, "im1")).FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(p1?.Message); // m1
Console.WriteLine(p2?.Image);  // im1
```

I don't know if that's what you want but it uses the same collection. BTW, change the Id properties to be decorated with `[BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the BsonDocument data type. It can do all of that. BsonDocument and dynamic back and forth is very convenient.

```
public class CustomObject{
      public long Id{get;set;}
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public List<(string,object)> CollectionDynamic{get;set;}
}

// inserted in mongo
    //public class CustomObject_in_Db{
    //          public long Id {get;set;}
    //          public string Name {get;set;}
    //          public string field2 {get;set;}
    //          public string field3 {get;set;}
    //          public string field4 {get;set;}
    //          public string field5 {get;set;}
    //    }
```

// something code... mapper(config)

```
Automapper.Mapper.CreateMap<BsonDocument,CustomObject>()
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.Id, a=>a.MapFrom(s=>s.Id.GetValue(nameof(CustomObject.Id)).AsInt64)
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.Name, a=>a.MapFrom(s=>s.Id.GetValue(nameof(CustomObject.Name)).AsString)
    .ForMember(dest=>dest.CollectionDynamic, a=>a.MapFrom(s=>_getList(s));
```

// .......

```
private List<(string, object)> _getList(BsonDocument source){
    return source.Elements.Where(e=>!typeof(CustomObject).GetProperties().Select(s=>s.Name).Any(a=>a ==e.Name)).Select(e=>e.Name, BsonTryMapper.MapToDotNetValue(e.Value)));
}
```