# Getting dynamic object instead of strong typed from MongoDB in .net core c#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I try to use MongoDB in combination with .net core (c#) to save some survey results.

The challenge is that I plan to make it as generic as possible to be able to add other rating controls later.

I am able to save different result types in one table.

```
public class VoteBase
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Control Control { get; set; }
    public string ControlType { get; set; }
}



public class VoteStarRatingControl : VoteBase
{
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
}



public class VoteStarRatingWithComment : VoteStarRatingControl
{
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I created a table of base type as MongoCollection:

```
        private readonly IMongoCollection<VoteBase> _voteBases;
```

To save it to that collection I used this code (where the DTO is same content datatransfer object to decouple the REST service from DB structure):

```
List<VoteBase> dbVotes = new List<VoteBase>();

foreach (VoteBaseDTO v in votes)
{
    switch (v) {
        case VoteStarRatingWithCommentDTO src:
            dbVotes.Add(new VoteStarRatingWithComment() { User = new User() { Id = UserId }, Control = new Control() { Id = src.ControlId }, Rating = src.Rating, Comment = src.Comment });
            break;
        case VoteStarRatingControlDTO sr:
            dbVotes.Add(new VoteStarRatingControl() { User = new User() { Id = UserId }, Control = new Control() { Id = sr.ControlId }, Rating = sr.Rating });
            break;
    }

}

_voteBases.InsertMany(dbVotes);

return dbVotes;
```

Until here all works fine.

Now I try to get the votes back for a specific list of controls (for one survey).

The following command fails with

**'Element 'Rating' does not match any field or property of class SurveyToolRestAPI.Models.VoteBase.'**

```
 object obj = _voteBases.Find(vb => vb.Control.Id == "5e9c24c50a099728b027e176").SingleOrDefault();
```

This is because it is of Type StarRatingControl instead of type VoteBase.

Is there a way to get the list as dynamic instead of strong typed from a MongoDB collection?

Comment: How about adding all the properties to the class and whatever can be null be annoted with  `[BsonIgnoreIfNull]` Mongodb is scheme less you can change/remove your scheme according to business

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Eldho, you pointed me to the right direction.

Doings some more research with the Bson... attributes I found the solution finally in this post [Mongodb collection as dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386687/mongodb-collection-as-dynamic)

The key is to add a BsonKnownTypes attribute. The it can be used as strong typed collection and the list will contain the appropriate subtypes.

```
    [BsonKnownTypes(typeof(VoteBase), typeof(VoteStarRatingControl), typeof(VoteStarRatingWithComment))]
```